# ffmpeg undefind symbol: err_set_debug_level

Tags: video, ffmpeg, libraries

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.  My ffmpeg has suddenly stopped working and is giving this error:

```
ffmpeg: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpocketsphinx.so.3: undefined symbol: err_set_debug_level
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling ffmpeg and I have tried uninstalling all of the packages related to pocketsphinx, but they are reinstalled when I install ffmpeg.  I'm not sure why it links to pocketsphinx but I can't get ffmpeg to do anything at all. When I use lddtree it looks like libavfilter is using libpocketsphinx.

I get this error when I try to use ffmpeg to do just about anything.

This command causes the error.

```
ffmpeg -i file.webm file.mp4
```

Even this command also causes the error

```
ffmpeg -h
```

But I get the same error if I try to convert to any other type of file.

Does anyone know anything I can try to troubleshoot this?

EDIT:

I've determined that I can delete the offending file and run:

```
sudo apt purge --auto-remove libpocketsphinx3
sudo apt-get install libpocketsphinx3
```

and it will put the file back in there.  But ffmpeg still will not run.

EDIT EDIT:

I can also remove the offending files by purging libpocketsphinx3.  After this if I reinstall ffmpeg:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

that will put the file back and will generate the error.  So this seems to be an issue that's coming in even with a fresh ffmpeg install

Comment: Please add the command you run and throws the error to the question.

Comment: Added to question.  But the answer really is ANY command with ffmpeg generates the same error.  Even ffmpeg -h

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same issue. Did you use sphinxbase? It's depreciated. Remove that and it should work.Also if you used an older version of pocketsphinx it builds with these shared libraries which will cause this I think.
Does `/usr/local/lib` contain a `libpocketsphinx.so.3` file? If not, create a `symlink` to `libpocketsphinx.so`:

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/libpocketsphinx.so /usr/local/lib/libpocketsphinx.so.3
```

Comment: This did all start after I tried to use something else that installed sphinxbase.  I tried removing it, but the shared library and the error remained.  I will check the second part of your answer shortly.

Comment: sphinxbase is already uninstalled as far as I can tell.  I tried creating the symlink you describe but it didn't change anything.

Comment: /usr/local/lib/libpocketsphinx.so.3 shows now?

Comment: No.  I misread the file name.  There's not actually a file by that name in usr/local/lib.  The link I created was broken from the start.

Comment: In /usr/local/lib is a file called libsphinxad.so.3.0.0 and one called libsphinxbase.so.3.0.0 but no libpocketsphinx.

Comment: Okay yes then I had that same issue, because I deleted the file after reading this post. I had to build and install the very first version that says not to use because of the shared libraries it created the files and worked. Once you build and install it create the system link then all will be good. https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/releases/tag/v5.0.0rc1